# how to avoid reflection errors after obfuscation with Proguard (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, proguard

i have obfuscated my classes and manualy updated my spring configuration xml's but the thing is , proguard changed the names of my setter methods and turned'em into something like

```
public void d(a a){
b= a;
}
```

so when spring tries to call by reflection setB("something")  it crashes .
what's a good way to avoid reflection errors when obfuscating ?
any thoughts

Answer (score 5):

You have to avoid obfuscating those classes. Use the [-keep](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html) options to exclude them. An alternative is to use [Spring JavaConfig](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) instead of XML; that way the configuration will also be obfuscated.

Comment: is there anyway i can convert xml configuration to java configuration when manual work ?

Comment: it's a real pain obfuscating  a spring project  :(

Answer (score 2):

According to the [spring bean schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd), a property name is defined as

> The name of the property, following JavaBean naming conventions.

And according to the [JavaBean specs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html), a setter should start with `set`.  You may be able to get around this by providing a *className*`BeanInfo` class to specify an alternative setter, but I guess Proguard will obfuscate away the name as well...

Comment: if i exclude all class with getters and setters i'll just end excluding the whole project , since were extensively using spring injections .

Comment: Personally I don't think obfuscation is necessarily worth the effort as a determined coder will be able to decompile the classes and extract strings and call flow using debug mode and decompilers and reengineer the code. Granted it takes more effort and time but it wont secure it.