Obfuscation of Java maven project with spring framework
I am facing org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException after the obfuscation is done.
Is there a way to avoid the changing of bean names, I have tried rules like -keep to keep the entire class or -dontobfuscate, regardless it always causes the above mentioned exception.
private Object getService(String serviceName) {
    return getInstance().getSpringContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
            .getBean(serviceName);

After obfuscation there are a number of beans missing from SpringContext because of which it throws error.
I have surfed through other questions regarding the issue I am facing but never found an answer
Is there a rule which specifically avoids changing the bean names, or is it a bad idea to obfuscate spring project or is there other methods for obfuscation of spring projects.
I have tried using @ComponentScan and specified a name, but it does not solve the issue, I have already used @Named and specified a name.
The class for which the exception is thrown:
//@Named("InterfaceMasterService")
//@Component("InterfaceMasterService")
@Service("InterfaceMasterService")
@Transactional("Transactional")
public class InterfaceMasterService {

The decompiled class after obfuscation
@Service("InterfaceMasterService")
@Transactional("Transactional")
public class InterfaceMasterService {


Which obfuscator do you use?

Note that this is not specific to spring projects - all frameworks using external configuration via some kind of text file (xml, json, yaml,...) that refer to code constructs by name face this issue. Even more generally - all code that uses reflection (e.g. for serialization) is problematic. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173526/how-to-avoid-reflection-errors-after-obfuscation-with-proguard-spring

Names for beans in spring are derrived from the classname. So if you change the classname, the bean name automatically changes. For @Bean methods the name of the method is the name of the bean, so if you change that the name of the bean changes etc. If you want the names to stay the same, explicitly name them in the @Component (or specialized annotation) or in the @Bean annotation.

@Hulk I have used proguard, I have seen the question you mentioned, the problem being I even tried using the dontobfuscate rule where none of the classes changed names, but somehow the bean name changes.

The first question which.comes into my mind: Why do you need to do that?

Obfuscation is way to modify the code so that people cannot know the working even after reverse engineering it, right ?

Obfuscation is way to modify the code so that people cannot know the working even after reverse engineering it, right ? No, it's just making things harder to decode, but in the end, the logic must be preserved and down to the metal the op code you can't obfuscate. Only thing you accomplish is to give classes, methods, variables and so on unmeaningful names, maybe scatter code around, so that it just takes more effort to get the logic behind. But code, which is worth to obfuscate, lets say you discovered an O(1) algo for the salesman problem, will always get attention from coders who can.

The only way to keep your secrets is to not give them away - e.g. if it only runs on your infrastructure, other people have a harder time figuring out how it works. The moment you give/sell it to someone, its 'only' a matter of how much effort it takes to figure it out (can still make a lot of difference).

Let's put it that way: if you have discovered a really big thing, protect it through hardware (own datacenter, security force, vaults, ... - you get the idea). If you think you have the new killer app, just pour money into it to stay in front of the upcoming competitors. No matter what you've done, the moment it gets out in the world, it'll either get copied or you get personal attention. Thus being said, it's completely time waisting to put effort into obfuscation, it comes always down to a race backed by money.

So is there no way to Obfuscate spring projects ?
Only issue I face is with bean names.

You can do many obfuscations to spring projects (which overall won't help a lot, but that's a different problem). Just make sure that any names that carry smeantic meaning (i.e. the ones that Spring uses to decide to do or not do stuff) stay unchanged: Bean class names, potentially parameter names if they are used ... obfuscating/removing local variable names and/or doing code obfuscation should not impact Spring.

Just make sure that any names that carry smeantic meaning (i.e. the ones that Spring uses to decide to do or not do stuff) stay unchanged Depending on your implementation that might get a bit tricky since Spring also derives actions from names, for eg JPA derived query methods. In a project like Spring there are a lot of contracts you've to follow, so bear that in mind, give everything explicit names and hope for the best ;)

You could explicitly set the bean names in your @Bean, @Component and @Service annotations so that the method/class names can be changed/obfuscated without changing the bean names.
I'm guessing that the bulk of your beans are injected via the type rather than the bean name so perhaps you'd only need to force the bean name for a handful of beans.
eg
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyConfiguration {
   @Bean("bean1")
   public Bean1 bean1() {
      return new Bean1();
   }

   @Bean(name="bean2", initMethod="init")
   public Bean2 bean2(Bean1 bean1) {
      return new Bean2(bean1);
   }
}

@Component("myComponent")
public class MyComponent { 
   ... 
}

@Service("myService")
public class MyService { 
   ... 
}

See

@Bean
@Component
@Service


Note that this partially defeats the purpose of obfuscation: the method/class will have a nonsense name, but there will be metadata attached to it that tells exactly what the name should be. In other words: I don't consider this much better than just excluding the names from renaming.

Agreed, but doing this config in the java files on the precise classes/methods might be nicer than some external obfuscator config file(s)

Yes, I agree. It's not pointless. It's just that the specific benefit of renaming methods is gone this way.

I tried, but still the error persists, the most confusing part is even after adding the rule -dontobfuscate the bean names changes, is there any rule to keep them unchanged ?

Which bean is throwing the NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ? Perhaps if you show the specific config for that exact bean (obfuscator config and @Bean config). Can you also decompile the obfuscated class file to see what's happened there?

I have modified the question with more details.

Perhaps InterfaceMasterService has been moved to a new package? And that package is not being component scanned?

Can you find the .class file that corresponds to the obfuscated InterfaceMasterService? Can you decompile the .class file and show what the obfuscator has done?

It has not been moved, when I just prevent obfuscation and deploy the jar, it works, but when I apply the obfuscation regardless of -dontobfuscate it messes up the beans.

I give up on you! I have asked you many times now to decompile .class file and you will not do it.

I have added the decompiled class, its the same.
I am keeping the entire class not obfuscating.

A normal spring boot app will do a component scan starting in the package of the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication. Has this class been obfuscated? Has the package changed?

This is not spring boot app, it uses spring

Are you doing any component scanning?

No, but I tried doing that, it did not work.

You'll need to do a component scan so that spring can find your classes annotated with @Service and @Component

I added a bean with the name InterfaceMasterService in xml file and now the error is solved.
Thanks for your help, greatly appreciate it.
